# Nativescript how to overflow text?

Tags: css, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using Nativescript with Vue.js and trying to overflow text. 
My text is in `Span` inside of `TextField` inside of `GridLayout` with 450 width and height. I want when the text length becomes larger than GridLayout's layout, just to overflow it, to get out from the layout.
Just like that: [image]

[Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=FxIwYQ) is my sample example in the playground and below is the source code.
I'm using `GridLayout`, because of some problems with NS Gestures when I'm using `AbsoluteLayout,FlexboxLayout` or `StackLayout`. `TextField` because there is moment when I want to edit the text. And `Span` instead of `Label`, because of some specifics on my code.

```html
<template>
    <Page>
        <GridLayout width="450" height="450" columns="150, 150,150" rows="150, 150,150">
            <TextField  id="textField" editable="false" backgroundColor="#43b883"
                row="0" col="0">
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." />
                </FormattedString>
            </TextField>

            <TextView id="textView" editable="false" backgroundColor="#1c6b48"
                row="1" col="0">
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." />
                </FormattedString>
            </TextView>

            <Label id="label" row=" 2" col="0" text="LabLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.el" />
        </GridLayout>      
    </Page>
</template>
```

**Is there a way to overflow the text like I want?**

**Or is there any other way to do it?**

Can I use something like css property *word-wrap* in NS? Tried with *textWrap* with the `Label`, but did not give the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow` is not a valid CSS attribute in {N} environment.

But you may let the label overflow beyond it's parent by using AbsoluteLayout and set `clipToBounds` to `false` in iOS / by calling `setClipChildren(false)` on the parent's native view in Android.

```
<template>
    <Page backgroundColor="gray">
        <AbsoluteLayout backgroundColor="red" width="200" height="200"
            ios:clipToBounds="false" @loaded="onLoaded">
            <Label class="m-5 h2 text-center" color="white"
                text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."></Label>

        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {};
        },
        methods: {
            onLoaded: function(args) {
                if (args.object.android) {
                    args.object.android.getParent().setClipChildren(false);
                    args.object.android.getParent().setClipToPadding(
                        false);
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: saves the day again. Thank you